# Angle of a rod with XY plane

Tags: vector-analysis, 3d

A rod which is in XY horizontal plane is released from its position with its one end fixed. Gravity acts in the direction of negative z-axis. At time t, the rod is making an angle θ with the z-axis.

I am getting a strong feeling that the angle made by the rod with x-axis, or the angle made by the plane containing the rod and the Z-axis and the XY plane is 90 - θ.

However, my textbook is considering that angle to be independent angle Φ

Then the coordinates of the other end of the rod is given as

x = l sinθ cosΦ

y = l sinθ sinΦ

z = l cosθ

[Rough Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUftR.jpg)

Is my assumption correct?

[UPDATE] - Its given that it is set rotating about the vertical axis with angular velocity ω, but will, or can this impact the answer?

Comment: The two angles, 1) "the angle made by the rod with x-axis", and 2) "the angle made by the plane containing the rod and the Z-axis and the XY plane", can be different. Using the later textbook notation $x=l\sin\theta\cos\phi$, the first angle would be $\cos^{-1}(x/l) = \cos^{-1}(\sin\theta\cos\phi)$.